# get first X characters + the substring after a certain substring in python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to obtain a substring in a string after the occurrence of a certain substring:

For example:

```
string="abcdefghijklmnoprst"
substring="def"
```

I want to obtain the first 5 characters along with the substring, so that the output should be:

```
defghijk
```

The problem here is, regards to my dataset, the substring and the locations of it will change constantly so that a code similar to this:

```
string="abcdefghijklmnoprst"
substring="def"

print(string[3:11])
```

would not work for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at regex (regular expression). `re.findall` is one starting point.

Answer (score 1):

This should work I believe, without using Regex:

```
string="abcdefghijklmnoprst"
substring="def"

start = string.index(substring)
end = start + len(substring) + 5
print(string[start:end])
```

Output:

```
defghijk
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex example

```
import re
string="abcdefghijklmnoprst"
substring="def"
re.findall(f'{substring}'+'.{5}', string) # -> ['defghijk']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

string="abcdefghijklmnoprst"
substring="def"

your_string = re.search(substring+r'.{5}', string).group()

print(your_string) #defghijk
```

Comment: Hi, consider adding an explanation of your code to add more long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

using python find() method might help

```
string = "abcdefghijklmnoprst"
substring = "def"

substring_index = string.find(substring)
print(string[substring_index:substring_index + 8])
```